# How to manually send OSGi events to the EventAdmin?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf

Currently, I would need to create a bundle that sends an event with `eventAdmin.sendEvent(event)`. However, for testing purposes it would be nice to be able to send events manually. Is that possible, using one or another OSGi shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a console extension that adds specific commands - in your case commands that create & send specific events. See [this documentation page](http://felix.apache.org/site/61-extending-the-console.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the [Apache Felix Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) also allows to manually send events.